# Fill a formula to the right to the last used column

Tags: vba, excel

Im fairly new to VBA. Im trying to write a code that will fill the formulas in cells D3 and D4 to the right and to the last column used minus 3. This is what I came up with but I dont think its quite right

```
Sub fillRight()

Dim lastColumn As Integer

lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3

    range("D3:D4").Select
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=range("D3", lastColumn), Type:=xlFillDefault
    range("D3", lastColumn).Select

End Sub
```

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: `range("D3", lastColumn)`-->`range("D3:D" & lastColumn)`

Comment: That fixed part of my code. The code seems to be filling my formula down. I am trying to fill my formulas to the right. i changed Type:=xlFillDefault ----> Type:=xlFillright but didnt get any luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
Sub fillRight()
    Dim lastColumn As Integer
    Dim rng_source As Range
    Dim rng_Destination As Range
    Dim l_SourceRows As Long

    Set rng_source = Range("D3:D4")
    l_SourceRows = rng_source.Rows.Count
    lastColumn = ActiveSheet.Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 3
    Set rng_Destination = Range(rng_source.Cells(1), Cells(rng_source.Cells(1).Row + l_SourceRows - 1, lastColumn))

    rng_source.AutoFill _
        Destination:=rng_Destination, _
        Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```

You were on the right path by setting your last column, but you also needed to know the last row in order to create a range for the last cell of the fill range.

Comment: That worked, I knew I was missing something. Thanks for the help. i appreciate it.